# How to set latitude/longitude delta to display routeCoordinates?

Tags: reactjs, algorithm, react-native, maps

I have this map, 
using react native map i can save the routeCoordinates :[{lat,lng},...] to display the lines after.

[image]

What i wanted to know/understand is how can i manage to adjust the region:

```
region={{
   latitude:
   longitude: 
   latitudeDelta: 
   longitudeDelta: 
}}
```

to be able to display all the routeCoordinates on the map. Maybe using the zoom of the map. 
My region is always centered using the starting point (routeCoordinates[0]).

Do i need to find the max distance between all of may coordinates ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map.fitBounds()` of Google maps API. This way map zooms in a way that is displaying all coordinates of your polyline.[Documentation Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.fitBounds)

```
const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var n = 0; n < myPointsArray.length ; n++){
    bounds.extend(points[n]);
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```